# Contact form after submission not redirecting to cms page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect, contact-form

I have created contact us page and called contact form block in content.When user submit for it redirect to contact/index instead of redirecting to current cms page that is contact-us.

I searched on internet but didn't found solution for magento 2.

Here is the code for contact form block:

```
   {{block class="Magento\\Contact\\Block\\ContactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form-contact.phtml"}}
```

Can anyone suggest me how can i redirect it to contact-us page instead of contact/index.

**UPDATE**

Here is my form-contact.phtml code:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */

        // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

        ?>
        <form class="form contact"
              action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
              id="contact-form"
              method="post"
              data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <div class="title-bonus-page">
                    <h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send your comments') ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                    <div class="left-input">
                        <div class="field name required">

                            <div class="control">
                                <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Name*')?>" name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field email required">

                            <div class="control">
                                <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Email*')?>" name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                               <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field telephone">

                            <div class="control">
                                <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Phone')?>" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                    <div class="field comment required">
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Message*')?>" name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                    <div class="actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                            <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send Message') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Send Message') ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

**Update 2**

The output of $block->getFormAction() is

```
 http://www.siteurl/contact/index/post/
```

Comment: Share code of template Magento_Contact::form-contact.phtml

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my  question above. Please check.

Comment: What is output of" echo $block->getFormAction()" i mean what is action URL of your form

Comment: I updated my question above. Please check.

Comment: After successfully submit your form url look like, http://www.siteurl/contact/index

Comment: This is the issue can you share the link/route how you are hitting your custom page, you are still using the magento contact form submit actin

Answer (score 8):

Contact Post Controller needs to be overridden here, because by default it redirects to `contact/index`

`$this->_redirect('contact/index');` needs to be changed to `$this->_redirect('cms-page-url-key');` in file `vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php`

Code for controller override is as follows :

**app/code/Custom/Contact/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Contact',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Custom/Contact/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Contact" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Custom/Contact/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Custom\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Custom/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Contact\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->clear('contact_us');
            $this->_redirect('contact-us');
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->getDataPersistor()->set('contact_us', $post);
            $this->_redirect('contact-us');
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }

}
```

Here `contact-us` is the cms page url key.

Comment: You can change the redirect to `$this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()` to redirect to the previous page so you don't need to know what the url key is.

Comment: I have fetch some error like Undefined property:$inlineTranslation so can you provide solution for this error.

Comment: @meet There seems to be some typo, the error means variable $inlineTranslation is not defined. Kindly share full error report and code.

Comment: Error show like below
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Custom\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor::$inlineTranslation in /app/code/Custom/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php on line 33

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Custom\Contact\Controller\Index\Post\Interceptor::$inlineTranslation in /app/code/Ktpl/CmsPages/Controller/Index/Post.php on line 33
#0 /app/code/Custom/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php(33): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 33, Array)

Comment: @meet Kindly share code for file app/code/Custom/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

Comment: @anshumishra i have post as answer so please review it

Comment: @meet This is not the correct way of asking any question on the stackExchange. Kindly post a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75235/discussion-between-meet-and-anshu-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your Controller. However, your form is missing form key `$block->getFormKey()`:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a great help getting me to the correct location, I found that all I had to do was create a new confirmation page, then change the file confirmation path (below).

Here is where I made my new confirmation path changes:
Line: 77
Line: 85

vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php